# how can i animate a pie with growing angle?

Tags: animation

**Hello everyone!**   I'm a beginner in **Blender**.   I have a problem.   How can I make this animation in **Blender**?   [image]   I've made it in another 3D software called **Cinema 4D**, but idk how to make it in **blender**.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

add a plane -> Tab -> M -> at center -> E Y 3

[image]

add screw and solidify modifier

[image]

check autosmooth

[image]

keyframe angle in screw modifier

[image]

[image]

---

Solution with geometry nodes:

[image]

Comment: Wow great
Thank you

Comment: you are welcome